# Mode of the array - method in Java

Tags: java, arrays

So I have this mode code that I wrote for my hw assigment and I need to figure out how to make the output not look so messed up.

Input example:

```
2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3
```

The output will be exactly the same (which is the mode) but I need it to be just `2` and `3` without them repeating.
Here is the code itself:

```
public static void runMode(int[] data) 
{
    int maxValue = -1;
    int maxCount = 0;
    int p = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < data.length; j++)
        {
            if(data[j] == data[i])
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if(count > maxCount)
        {
            maxCount = count;
            maxValue = data[i];
        }  
    }
    System.out.print("Mode: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < data.length; j++)
        {
            if(data[j] == data[i])
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if(count == maxCount)
        {
            System.out.print(data[i] + ", ");
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** `HashMap` and `ArrayList` are unfortunately not allowed to be used in the assignment.

Comment: OK, so your algorithm is 1) find the element that appears the most times, and remember the count it appears maxCount 2) loop through the array again and print any element that appears maxCount times. So you're necessarily going to print each mode value maxCount times since you'll find it maxCount times as you loop through the array. I'm not sure what best to suggest: you can either keep track of ties as you count the mode in the first place, e.g. by making maxValue a list, or you can keep track of numbers you've printed e.g. in a set and ignore duplicates.

Comment: Use a `Map` to accumulate a count for each _distinct_ data value; the data values will be the _keys_ in the `Map`, the counts will the _values_.  Then scan over the _values_ to find the maximum count.  Finally, scan over the map entries, and print out the _key_ for each _value_ that's equal to the maximum count.

Comment: Make new array at the start `int[] r = new int[data.length]; ` store values in it if they don't repeat later use that array

Comment: Are you allowed to sort the list? Then you can loop through the list and count the number of each in a single pass, and then update the max or print the matching mode when the value in the list changes, or you reach the end of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might seem a bit complicated but I think if you edit the code after the line `System.out.print("Mode: ");` to what is shown in my demo, then it should give you the output that you are looking for. Here's the demo:

```
System.out.print("Mode: ");
int[] dataCounted = new int[data.length]; // This array will hold the values that are the mode
int value = -1; // Value of the number you're testing for, not how many of the number there is
int index = 0; // Index for the dataCounted array
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
    value = data[i];
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < data.length; j++)
    {
        if (data[j] == data[i])
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == maxCount)
    {
        boolean used = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < index; j++) 
        {
            if (value == dataCounted[j]) 
            {
                used = true;
            }
        }

        if (!used) 
        {
            dataCounted[index++] = value;
            System.out.print(data[i] + ", ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! this actually works, you just saved my grade